# How to pass object it has array to action on AJAX

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-core

I have an object in AJAX and it has a list of properties. I want to pass this object to my action. But all the time list is `null`. How can I fix it? Here is my code:

Classes :

```
public class SaveProduct
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Code { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public decimal Price { get; set; }
        public string UnitW { get; set; }
        public int Amount { get; set; }
        public List<SaveProductDetail> Details{ get; set; }
    }
public class SaveProductDetail
    {
        public int id { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
    }
```

Ajax: I tried to keep the names same.

```
 $("#sepeteEkleButton").click(function () {
        var Code = $("#productName").val();
        var Id = $("#productId").val();
        var Description = $("#productDescription").val();
        var UnitW = $("#productUnitW").val();
        var Price = $("#productPrice").val();
        var Amount = $("#productAmount").val();
        var array = [];
        $("select[data-knownid=1]").each(function () {
            var selectedId = $(this).attr("data-savename");
            var selectedName = $(this).find('option:selected').text();
            array.push({ id: selectedId, name: selectedName });
            if (selectedId == 3) {
                //data-savenameDetay=""
                var fabricDetailId = $("#configdetail option:selected").attr("data-secretmark");
                var fabricDetailName = $("#configdetail option:selected").text();
                array.push({ id: fabricDetailId, name: fabricDetailName });
            }
        });
        var arr = { Code: Code, Id: Id, Description: Description, UnitW: UnitW, Price: Price, Amount: Amount, Details: array };
        $.ajax({
            type: 'get',
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            url: '/Panel/PD',
            data: arr,
            cache: false,
            dataType: 'json'
        });
    });
```

and my controller

```
 public JsonResult PD (List<SaveProductDetail> array)
        {
            return Json(null);
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is a simple demo,you can check it.

```
<button id="button">Test</button>

@section Scripts
{
<script>

    $('#button').click(function () {
        var array = [];
        array.push({ id: 1, name: "aa" });
        array.push({ id: 2, name: "bb" });
        var arr = {
            Code: "Code",
            Id: 1,
            Description: "aaa",
            UnitW: "UnitW",
            Price: 12,
            Amount: 1,
            Details: array
        };
        $.ajax({
            data: JSON.stringify(arr),
            url: '/Panel/PD',
            datatype: 'json',
            type: 'POST',
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            });

    });
</script>
}
```

In your action:

```
 public JsonResult PD ([FromBody] SaveProduct model)
    {
        return Json(null);
    }
```

Test result:

[image]

Comment: ty for answer .i followed ur way. but dont work. ur ''detail' array has static members. i want to make this dynamic.  If i delete this Details its work. But when i write dont work.

Comment: I'm sorry I didn't understand your needs too well, can you explain it?

Comment: i checked ur edited comment. its work. It was my bad. Thank you soo much. U saved me from my boss xD